# Vote without score?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit, voting, score

Maybe I'm interpreting this picture incorrectly, but it looks like a vote without score. As far as I can tell I got a single upvote and no downvotes for both these questions, but the '10' doesn't show up..

[image: Pointless votes]

Comment: And as I post this, I wonder if it has anything to do with hitting the daily cap. :-o . If so, I apparently don't do that often enought, cos I can't say I noticed this before. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have indeed hit the daily cap. Click the "today" tab to get all the votes from today. You will see that they add up to 200 + any points from accepted answers.

Comment: They do indeed. I thought the daily cap was at 150, but it must have changed or I just don't remember correctly. Will take me a while to get that Legendary badge this way. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look jon skeet's reputation tracker

http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=511529&sf=&su=&meta=&mode=yesterday&showzero=true

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It actually shows the same score, but the '0' seems clearer than just an empty spot.